# how to do type conversion for pointer type in java like in c/c

Tags: java, c

In c/c++, one can do things like

```
float b = 3.;
int a = *(int*)&b;
```

I want to do the same thing in java, is it possible and if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a programming problem you're trying to solve, or are you just trying to make sure that Java and C have different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have pointers. For this specific case, you can use [`Float.intBitsToFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) (and [`Float.floatToIntBits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29) for the other way; `Double` also has similar methods). There is, however, no way to do funkier "conversions".

Answer (score 3):

There is no `POINTER` kind of thing in JAVA. JAVA has a feature called Memory Management or say GC(Garbage collector) to handle all the memory related operations for you. You are not allowed to access any memory block by using memory address.

Comment: Although it should be noted that garbage collection and pointers aren't mutually exclusive. The .NET Framework has a garbage collector _and_ pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`Pointers` are not available in java. You have to work with `Object`.

```
Float f = new Float(3.0);
Integer i = Math.round(f);
```

Comment: i know. that is why i am asking. :)

Answer (score 0):

Java implements everything based on pointers. So any object variable in Java will be passed as pointer reference. They made it invisible to Java developer.
To convert from float or double to int, you can simply try

```
double b = 3.0;
int a = (int)b;
```

Be aware that if b = 1.x then a = 1

Comment: Can't you do lit also in c?

Comment: Casting a double into an int and reading the double bits as if they were an int are two very different things, and OP is trying to do the second one.